# Loading HTML files in ion-slide

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic. I have been trying to load several HTML files into the ion-slide. I already try out several solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543111/set-a-different-html-file-in-ion-slide) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037664/ion-slide-with-different-template). Here is my code

```
  <ion-view style="" title="Forum">
  <ion-content class="has-header" padding="true" >
  <ion-slide-box>
  <ion-slide>
  <h3 class="text-center">slide2</h3>
  <ng-include src="'tes.html'"></ng-include>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
  <h3 class="text-center">slide3</h3
  <ng-include src="'tes2.html'"></ng-include>
  </ion-slide>
  </ion-slide-box>
  </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

The problem is that the page only shows the slide2 word and can be slide to slide3 but all of that slide do not content the HTML. The thing is that i'm still experimenting it on firefox browser. Is it because the browser or is there any special restriction for ng-include? [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CvG31xdHSSMfHlmQf8Es?p=preview)

Comment: Please add a plunker

Comment: and it should be <ng-include src="tex.html"></ng-include> remove the single quotes from within.

Comment: I try removing the single quote, it still doesnt work..

Comment: I ll answer this by tonight

Comment: Do you find anything?

Comment: Oh i just forgot.. give me 6 more hours... I ll get it done anyhow.